# Always has been / has always been

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm deeply sorry for my poor english skills but I need to know. :(

Can I answer: "It always has been happening" after the sentence: "This is happening because of you" ?

Comment: *Has always been* is grammatical.  Adverbs are placed between the auxiliary verb (has) and the main verb (been).  This is evident in this sentence: "He's always been fun."

Comment: Most adverbs modifying a verb phrase may be placed before or after an auxiliary verb in its verb chain: _It frequently has been prepared there; It has frequently been prepared there; It has been frequently prepared there_ are all grammatical and mean the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Adverbs of frequency (always) are rarely used in the continuous tense. It is preferred to use simple tenses instead. So, instead of Present Perfect Continuous, I would choose Present Perfect Simple. But since "It has always happened" would not address what you mean, the fact that something has always been the trend, I would choose Present Simple. So your answer would be **It always happens.**

Comment: That's a quite different sentence, with a different (though apropos) meaning.

Comment: "Continuous" is an aspect, not a tense (or even part of the name of a tense). Anyway, present perfect continuous would be "It has always been happening".

Comment: “It happens regularly” might capture the meaning the questioner seeks.

Comment: "Adverbs of frequency (always) are rarely used in the continuous tense." Really? "He is always making this kind of mistake", "This is always happening to me", "I am always running into people I know at the store"...